# Override PHP Cache-Control Header from Apache config?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, http-headers

PHP is setting the Cache-Control header in multiple places. I don't want to break my code upgrade path, but I'd like to change the Cache-Control header in Apache config instead. However, it looks like PHP headers taking precedence. Is there a way to make sure that Apache's Cache-Control headers win?

Comment: You mean you don't want to _fix_ your code.

Comment: I'd prefer not to break the upgrade path.

Comment: Please post your Apache config, especially in cache-control config